# Passando id para impressão de pdf com cakephp3 e tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf, id, tcpdf

Pessoal estou gerando relatórios em pdf e estou com o seguinte problema, eu preciso setar o id do voluntario para imprimir o pdf com os dados do voluntario, tentei da seguinte forma pelo link:

view

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Imprimir'), ['action' => 'pdf_view2', $voluntario->id], ['class'=>'btn btn-info btn-xs']) ?>
```

acontece que mesmo assim a impressão de pdf obedece apenas ao id que eu passo no controller, so que se eu passar null, vem nulo, se eu passar o id normal como 2... vem o voluntario numero 2... como eu consigo passar o id do voluntario para o pdf_view?

controller

```
public function pdf_view2($schedule_id = null, $id = 2){        
      $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax');
      $this->set('title', 'My Great Title');
      $this->set('file_name', '2016-06' . '_June_CLM.pdf');
     $this->response->type('pdf');


  /*  $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Oficinas']
    ];
    $voluntarios = $this->paginate($this->Voluntarios);
    

    $this->set(compact('voluntarios'));*/

    $voluntario = $this->Voluntarios->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Oficinas']
    ]);

    

    $this->set('voluntario', $voluntario);
```

Preciso tirar esse id=2 e colocar de forma que ele pegue o id do voluntário, como fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Seu método deve ficar assim:

```
    public function pdf_view2($schedule_id = null, $id = null)
    {
      $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax');
      $this->set('title', 'My Great Title');
      $this->set('file_name', '2016-06' . '_June_CLM.pdf');
      $this->response->type('pdf');
      
      $voluntario = $this->Voluntarios->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Oficinas'],
        ]);

        $this->set('voluntario', $voluntario);
    }
```

Aqui nesta linha:

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Imprimir'), ['action' => 'pdf_view2', $voluntario->id], ['class'=>'btn btn-info btn-xs']) ?>
```

Você precisar ver o que está sendo passado em **$voluntario->id**

É o que está indo para o parâmetro. Precisa ver se está carregando passando o id corretamente!

Comment: não funcionou... o id vai na url direitinho ... mas por algum motivo ele n retorna o voluntario no pdf... so retorna quando eu defino ele na função do controller

Comment: Atualizei a resposta! Verifica o valor de $voluntario->id.

Comment: conseguir amigo.. muito obrigado pela ajuda, o valor do voluntario id estava ok...  um rapaz do facebook me aconselhou e eu apenas troquei de lugar o $schedule_id = null e o $id = null kkk de toda forma muito obrigado por me ajudar

Answer (score -1):

Muda essa linha:

```
public function pdf_view2($schedule_id = null, $id = 2){
```

Para:

```
public function pdf_view2($id = null, $schedule_id = null){
```

Sua função recebe o `ID` da sua URL no primeiro parâmetro e não no segundo.